# On Rényi entropy/divergence

Tags: real-analysis, it.information-theory

The Rényi entropy for a probability density function $f$ with dominating measure $\mu$ of order $\alpha>0$ is defined as 
$$H_\alpha(f)={1 \over {\alpha-1}}\log\int f^\alpha d\mu.$$
If $f$ is smooth enough, as $\alpha \to 1$, the limit is the classical Shannon entropy
$$H_1(f)=\int f\log f d\mu.$$
The Rényi entropy naturally defines a class of divergence
$$M_\alpha(f,g)={1 \over {\alpha-1}}\log\int f^\alpha g^{1-\alpha} d\mu.$$
For fixed $f,g$ smooth enough, the limit divergence as we push $\alpha \to 1$ is the classical Kullback-Leibler divergence
$$M_1(f,g)=\int f\log {f \over g} d\mu.$$
Now let's consider a slightly more complicated scenario: If $||g_\alpha/g||_\infty=1+o(1)$, then
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
M_\alpha(f,g_\alpha)&={1 \over {\alpha-1}}\log\int f^\alpha g^{1-\alpha}\bigg(\frac{g_\alpha}{g}\bigg)^{1-\alpha} d\mu\\
&={1 \over {\alpha-1}}\bigg(\log \int f^\alpha g^{1-\alpha} d\mu+(1-\alpha)\log(1+o(1)\bigg)\\
&\to M_1(f,g).
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
However, at the entropy level, the simple argument wouldn't apply to show
$$H_\alpha(f_\alpha) \to H_1(f)$$
even if $||f_\alpha/f||_\infty=1+o(1)$. This is also tricky when think about divergence in its first entry. Is this something special about the asymmetry of the divergence $M_\alpha(\cdot,\cdot)$? Is there counterexample for which the convergence fails if $||f_\alpha/f||_\infty=1+o(1)$? Or any possible convergence conditions on $f_\alpha \to f$, without controlling the rate of convergence in terms of $\alpha$ that guarantees the convergence?